# Changing Values of a Row in a 2D Array Using For Loops

Tags: c++, arrays, function, row

I have a function called `zero_row`. This function inserts the value of zero into all a row that is specified. The function takes to variables. `a` (the array) and `row` (the row in the array). Here is my function

```
void zero_row (int a [4][5], int row){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        a[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

I know how to set values of the entire array to zero. As i have a function to do this as well.

```
void zero_all (int a [4][5]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            my_arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to do this using the variable `row`. I want to use this variable so I can later change the row in my main function, like so: `zero_row(a, 3);`. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the first index corresponds to a row and the second index corresponds to a column.

Use

```
void zero_row (int a [4][5], int row){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  // 5 instead of 4
        a[row][j] = 0;
    }
}
```